# Venn diagram in Python

Tags: python, diagram

Is someone knows how can I code this on python? I know this should not been ask but I literally confused on how can I code this illustration, still don't have the idea where to start, can anyone help me?

[image]

**This is the given question**

**unordered collection of unique objects**

```
a = {100, 3.12, False, "Bye"}
b = {100, 3.12, False, "Welcome"}
```

**Set of operations**

```
#Convert  a list to a set
my_set = set([1,1,2,3])


#Add an item to the set
a.add(4)

#Remove an item from a set
a.remove("Bye")

#Returns set a minus b
a.difference(b)

#Returns intersection of set a and b
a.intersection(b)

#Returns the union of set a and b
a.union(b)

#Returns True if a is a subset of b, false otherwise
a.issubset(b)

#Returns True if a is superset of b, false otherwise
a.issuperset(b)
```

Comment: Define `code this illustration`. What is the given input, and what is the desired output?

Comment: You can draw using the turtle module.

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: I've added some question below, need help

Comment: I do not see any question. "*can anyone help me?*" is not a valid question on this site.

Comment: @mozway I've added it at the bottom, set of operations

Comment: I don't see any question. There are only commented lines of code.